# rails migration apparently causing infinite forking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, rake-task

I've encountered a problem today that I've so far not had any luck tracking down.  I created a new migration file (via 'rails g migrate ...').  After creating the file, when I run rails db:migrate or rails db:migrate:status, the result is that rails appears to be infinitely starting itself - i.e., forking.  If I remove the new migration file, this no longer happens - e.g., rails db:migrate:status results in the status report displaying and completing.  To verify that rails was forking when I ran the migration, I ran, in a separate terminal:

```
while :; do date;echo ....................;pgrep -laf ruby; sleep 1; done
```

After starting up the 'rails db:migrate', the following pattern appears from the above command:

```
Tue Feb 26 09:59:59 CST 2019
....................
23799 /home/jtc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby bin/rails db:migrate:status
Tue Feb 26 10:00:02 CST 2019
....................
23799 /home/jtc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby bin/rails db:migrate:status
23819 ruby bin/rails db:test:prepare
23837 /usr/bin/ruby-mri /home3/development/jtc/projects/s-todo/src/main/initial-
processing.rb
Tue Feb 26 10:00:03 CST 2019
....................
23799 /home/jtc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby bin/rails db:migrate:status
23819 ruby bin/rails db:test:prepare
Tue Feb 26 10:00:04 CST 2019
....................
23799 /home/jtc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby bin/rails db:migrate:status
23819 ruby bin/rails db:test:prepare
23875 ruby bin/rails db:test:prepare
Tue Feb 26 10:00:06 CST 2019
....................
23799 /home/jtc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby bin/rails db:migrate:status
23819 ruby bin/rails db:test:prepare
23875 ruby bin/rails db:test:prepare
23886 ruby bin/rails db:test:prepare
```

As you can see, the command that is forking is  'ruby... db:test:prepare'.  A couple more details:

Other rails (non db:) tasks (all I've tried so far) produce the same behavior - i.e., forking when the new migration file is in place, and running normally when it's not there.  When I run the rails server, this problem does not occur.  I believe it is only occurring when running rails/rake tasks.  Also, I suspected that changes I had made to config/application.rb might be causing it.  But after trying a couple older versions of that file (dates at which migrations were not forking) and running into the same problem, I've concluded that it is probably not a factor.  Finally, I've also noticed that rails tasks are lately running with the test framework - i.e., at the end of a run (without the new migration file), I see this:

```
Progress: |====================================================================|
Run options: --seed 37369

# Running:

Finished in 0.00505s
0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

Finished in 0.004874s, 0.0000 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
0 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

I strongly suspect that the two problems are related.  I've started investigating what I've changed since the last successful migration (on Feb 13), but have not found any suspects yet.

As I'm sure you all can tell, I'm far from a rails expert.  Any clues or pointers on where to look to solve the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the cause of the problem.  I thought I'd answer my own question here in case it helps others with a similar problem.  I discovered that when you run a rails task, all of your tasks are loaded (all the *.rake files under lib/tasks/, I presume).  I decided to hide my *.rake files (in a chmod 000 directory) and restore them 1 or 2 at a time to find out if one of them was causing the problem; and, doing this, I found the culprit - a rake task that re-used some of my test code to create some model instances, and insert corresponding records into the database, in order to test/debug a (what I call) service I had been working on.  Obviously, that's why the test framework was being run even though the problem showed up in development mode - since all the rake files are loaded, that test code was loaded, too...  And since with ruby loading the code implies some code being executed, the test code being loaded must have caused the test environment to be set up - and, as well, some cyclic dependency must have been triggered by executing that "borrowed" test code, resulting in a sort of infinite recursion and  forking.  (I didn't investigate the exact cause of that, since it could take some time and stopping it involves simply commenting out the offending code, or removing the rake file. I ended up surrounding the offending code with a guard - i.e. "if ENV['ODD_ENV_VAR'] then ... end", so that I can still use it when I need it.)

So for anyone seeing the same symptoms - infinite forking and/or the test framework being run in dev mode (or perhaps similar odd problems) that occurs only when running rails/rake tasks, I'd say the rake files should be the first place to look at, even before using 'git checkout...' in order to find out when the problem was introduced.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you haven't done something sensible like using git or something to track your versioning (if so, just roll back everything).

Just in case I'd stop (or `kill` if necessary) any `spring` that's running.

Re troubleshooting this issue, I'd recommend creating a new app and copying over your migrations and running them in the new app, to confirm it's not your migrations.  Then just copy over your `app` and other changes.  Then install and use `git` or something like it to make problems like this trivial to resolve in future :)